# selecting HTML element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I use a class named row across my site

```
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image: Like this in image]

And here I want to target this specific one to make the display property flex and after this to target the class works-step inside it to make the display property inline-block so they appear side by side because now it appears like this

[image: Like in this Gif]

I tried this

```
section .row:second-child {
  display: flex;
}
section .row:second-child .works-step{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Create [mre] using <> button in the editor and add all relevant code here, not with external links and especially not images.

Comment: If you wanna make the columns side by side, use `display: flex;` on `.row`. You do not need to set display properties on the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector needs to be `section .row .steps-box:nth-child(2) .works-steps { ... }` (you * can*  use `>` in-between to be even more specific, but it's probably not necessary.

`:nth-child(...)` refers to the child element itself, i.e. the *child* element that is the nth child of its parent, in your case `.steps-box` as the second child element of `.row`

Answer (score 0):

1. You've chosen the wrong ***Css class pseudo selector***. `.row:second-child` is not a correct selector. You can use `.row:nth-child(2)`. You can read about *Css class pseudo selectors* [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).
2. According to No. 1 that's why `display: inline-block` is not working on `.works-step`. You must replace these codes instead of the code you wrote at the top.

```
/* According to the second .row */
section:nth-child(2) {
   display: flex;
}

/* According to section > LAST .row > LAST .steps-box */
section:nth-child(2) {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

3. If you want to place the `works-step` side by side, you can simply set the display of its parent to *flex* (`.steps-box`). You can ignore using `display: inline-block` for `.works-step`, cause flex is more preferred and easy to use.

```
.steps-box {
   display: flex;
}
```